# Facebook Share Button data-href Wordpress Permalink Displays: "facebook.com/v2.0..."

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

This is how I render my button:

```
function fb_share() {
    $permalink = get_permalink();
    echo '<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="'.$permalink.'" data-layout="button_count"></div>';
}
```

I include the scripts right after  tag opens. However, what it does when you click share is:

[image: Facebook screenshot]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because I have been testing my theme using MAMP and having the string "localhost" in the browser URL. As @dustincaruso mentioned:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code directly in the PHP/HTML markup of your theme. It will create a link to the current page/URL in the "data-href" attribute.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

Comment: Hasan - i've edited the code now that i know you're using it in "the loop" - try it now.

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I have been doing. It results in the very same thing happening.

Comment: Hasan - the_permalink _should_ work within in the_loop. i'm confused. i'd be happy to take a look at your code if you'd like.

Comment: Hasan - i put the same code i gave you earlier into my site just to see if it would work and it does - check it out for yourself - http://dustincaruso.com/blog/ - all i did was (1) copy lines 36 through 43 from the header.php file in your git repo (the Facebook JavaScript) and pasted it in my file towards the top - and then (2) used the exact code above that i gave you in "the loop" and the share dialog works just fine.

Comment: Yes, it does work on the server. It also worked on my website as well. The problem seems to be with localhost string in the URL, when testing using MAMP. The exact same thing does not work then. Thanks Dustin.